# Javascript clear content of selectbox

Tags: javascript

As part of my populating selectbox function I am clearing the contents of the populated select box and then inserting options to a empty box. Although the select box is not being cleared correctly and a lot of options are not removed. I am using the following code to clear the contents of the select box:

```
for(var i = 0; i < document.getElementById(selectbox).options.length; i++)
    document.getElementById(selectbox).options[i] = null;
```

Why not all the options are removed from the selectbox?

Comment: Sorry my bad. It shouldnt be there.

Comment: sooo does it work without the -1? If not, I would guess that is becuase the length of the `document.getElementByID(selectbox.options.length` is changing as you remove elements from it. I do not know this for sure as I am far from Javascript pro though.

Comment: @thatidiotguy good idea lemme check it.

Comment: @thatidiotguy I would have guessed like you but I'm too lazy to check for confirmation (maybe it works with reverse looping) when there are simpler solutions.

Comment: @thatidiotguy unfortunately your idea didnt solve the problem.

Comment: @dystroy agreed, but its a good learning case potentially for debugging.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can simply do

```
 document.getElementById(selectbox).options.length = 0;
```

You could also have removed the elements one by one, almost like you did, but you must take into account the fact the length of `options` changes when you iterate. The correct way to remove while iterating would have been

```
for (var i=document.getElementById(selectbox).options.length; i-->0;)
    document.getElementById(selectbox).options[i] = null;
```

But the first solution is simpler of course.

Comment: Can you test also the other solution ? I'm sure @thatidiotguy will be as interested than me by the result.

Comment: Good. Thanks for the test :)

Comment: First solution is working great when compared to second

Answer (score 1):

```
var selectbox = document.getElementById(selectbox);

document.getElementById("emptyBox").innerHTML = selectbox.innerHTML;
selectbox.innerHTML = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative and more terse method of clearing all options of a select list, we can take advantage of JavaScript's falsey value of zero and then simply remove the option from the Dom:

```
function clearSelectList(list) {
    // when length is 0, the evaluation will return false.
    while (list.options.length) {
        // continue to remove the first option until no options remain.
        list.remove(0);
    }
}
```

Usage would then be:

```
var list = document.getElementById("selectbox");
clearSelectList(list);
```

Or more succinctly:

```
clearSelectList(document.getElementById("selectbox"));
```

Answer (score 0):

this example with new generation JavaScript. I do recommend to use.

```
[...cbrCenterSelectbox.options].forEach(option => option.remove())
```